# How do I output name instead of ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails newbie here! I have a `has_many_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between `items` and `builds`.

In the code provided below, the ID of the items are being displayed instead of the name of the item with that ID. How do I display the name of the item?

```
<% current_user.builds.each do |build| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= build.hero.name%></td> 
    <td><%= build.user.email%></td> 
    <td><%= build.name %></td> 
    <td><%= build.starting_items %></td> 
    <td><%= build.early_items %></td> 
    <td><%= build.core_items %></td> 
    <td><%= build.situational_items %></td> 
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mapped  association (has_one) in model with Hero and User, then probably you can use following code:

```
build.hero.field_name # Where field_name is column name from Hero Model
```

Please let me know if this will work for you or not.

Comment: I just figured that one out by myself, so I altered the question to find an answer to my current problem :D